# Spring MVC JSON deserialization with malformed JSON ( Jackson )

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

On a REST api i receive a Json that gets mapped to a Java Object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ReturnObject doReturn(@RequestBody ProblemObject requestBody)
```

The object is simple:

```
public class ProblemObject implements Serializable {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public ProblemObject(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }  

    public ProblemObject(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

The problem is Jackson tries to deserialize even malformed JSON, with not so good results, for example it accepts:

```
 "field1": "test",
 "field2": "test"
}
```

notice no opening brace. This causes the object to get mapped with field1 having a value of "field2" and field2 being null.
It also accepts no comma with even worse results.
For now the only alternative i can think of is implementing a custom deserialiser but that is not optimal imho.
Is there a way to make Jackson more strict?

Comment: My suggestion is to use some kind of JSON validator and if the validity test fail just throw an exception. Jackson properties in application.properties does not seem to have any options to set how strict Jackson should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in the TokenBuffer in Jackson. An [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1494) has been opened and a Jackson dev has confirmed the bug.
It is due to the single String constructor. Removing the constructor if possible is a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I would try being more explicit in your `@RequestMapping` annotation and telling the API what it should be consuming:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still accepts the JSON with no opening brace.

Comment: You have a misconfiguration then. You should be getting a 415 response. Do you mind editing your post and adding your web MVC configuration?

Comment: It's spring boot with web dependency, default configuration. The code you see is inside a controller with \@RestController. Jackson v2.8.1, Spring boot v1.4.0.RELEASE

Comment: i posted a bugreport to jackon with an example project: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1494

Comment: For some reason, your single argument `String` constructor is allowing Jackson to accept the malformed JSON. It doesn't error even if you just pass "blah" (no braces) to the endpoint. If you remove that constructor, everything works fine. Not really a solution, but you are right this might be a bug.

Comment: Yes you are indeed right and a Jackson dev confirmed the bug.